# Does eigenvalues of matrix change after multiplication by unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, does multiplication by a unitary matrix $U$ change the eigenvalues of $A$? So for:

$$Ax = \lambda x \qquad \mathrm{and} \qquad AUy = \mu y $$

does $\lambda = \mu$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$?

I know the above is true for doing left and right multiplication by $U$:

$$ UAU^*y = \mu y \\ 
AU^*y = \mu U^* y \\
Az = \mu z \\
\therefore \mu = \lambda$$

(defining $z = U^* y$)

Under the guise that unitary matrices are simply rotations, it logically makes sense to me that $\mu$ and $\lambda$ should be identical, and only the the eigenvectors should be different. The statement is true for singular values (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3986501/486538)), but I'm having trouble proving it for eigenvalues (if it even is true).

#### Edit

After a quick example in python, I understand that the above is *not* true. So instead: **where is my thought process going wrong with regard to how unitary matrices/rotations effect eigenvalues?**

#### Edit 2

What I was really going for, but did not state correctly was that:

$$AX = \Lambda X \qquad \mathrm{and} \qquad AUY = MY \\$$

such that $ \lambda \in M, \forall \lambda \in \Lambda$, where $M$ and $\Lambda$ are diagonal matrices.

Comment: Are you assuming no relationship between $x$ and $y$? Take $U$ to be the identity matrix (which is unitary): then it looks like what you're asking is whether $Ax=\lambda x$ and $Ay=\mu y$ imply $\lambda = \mu$, which is basically asking whether any two eigenvalues of $A$ are equal, which is of course not true.

Comment: I'm mainly focused on the eigenvalues here. I'd imagine there would be a relationship between $x$ and $y$ in your example (in that case, $y = Ix$).

Comment: Also, note my edit. I now know that my initial assertion was wrong, so I'm more trying to figure out where my understanding is wrong. Unless I'm missing something important in your example using $U=I$.

Comment: You are stating some fact (which you already know to be false) and asking where does your thought process go wrong when deriving this fact; I'm saying that the fact is wrong by a much simpler argument, namely that it implies that any matrix has at most 1 eigenvalue. This has nothing to do with rotations or eigenvalues per se, it's just that in your current formulation $x$ and $y$ are two unrelated vectors and thus there's hardly anything useful you could say about them in general.

Comment: I guess I'm hoping for an explanation in terms of the effect that the unitary matrix has on $A$ such that the above statement is false (or that the above statement implies there is at most 1 eigen value). Something in terms of U changing range/null space.

Comment: In other words, I made a statement based on intuition, that I later found out (and you gave a simple example proving) was wrong. Now I'm trying to figure out where my intuition was wrong.

Comment: I strongly believe we're having a huge misunderstanding here. As I've said, this has nothing to do with $U$ or how it acts on anything. Let's start simpler: do you understand why $Ax=\lambda x$ together with $Ay = \mu y$ does **not** imply $\lambda = \mu$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. But I know that $\mu = \lambda$ iff $\lambda$ has multiplicity greater than 1 or $x = y$.

Comment: Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$. We have $Ax=\lambda x$ with $x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\lambda=2$, while $Ay=y$ with $x=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mu=3$. Yet, $\lambda \neq \mu$, that is, $2 \neq 3$.

Comment: I think my understanding/intuition might be better served in trying to understand the differences between eigenvalues vs singular values. ie. Why the statement is true for singular values and not eigenvalues.

Comment: It is not true that **any** singular value of a matrix is equal to **any** singular value of the rotated matrix (which is your your statement with eigenvalues replaces with singular values). What is true is that there is a bijective correspondence between singular values of a matrix and singular values of the rotated matrix.

Comment: Ok, maybe that's the misunderstanding you were talking about before. I'm referring to having a bijective correspondence eigenvalues of a matrix and of it's rotated matrix. So that the spectrum of $A$ has the same spectrum as $AU$.

Comment: I've updated the question with what (I think) is more along the lines of what I was thinking.

Comment: @JamesWright The absolute value of the product of all the eigenvalues of $A$ and the absolute value of the product of the all the eigenvalues of $AU$ will be equal. This can be proven easily by noting that the (1) the determinant is equal to the product of eigenvalues of a matrix, (2) $\text{det}(AU) = \text{det}(A)\text{det}(U)$ and (3) $|\text{det}(U)| = +1$.

Comment: For intuition building I've been seeking an algebraic proof of the facts I mentioned in the last comment without relying on the "complicated" alternating multilinear formulas for $\text{det}(A)$, but have not yet had success. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4325195/proof-that-textdetab-textdeta-textdetb-without-explicit-expres?noredirect=1#comment9017897_4325195

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is somewhat correct, but you are doing it wrong. When you mean a rotation, to what does it apply? To vectors, right?

So, if $A$ is the matrix of a linear map , we expect that if we rotates the axes, the the matrix changes, but the application is still the same, so the eigenvalues should be the same. Let's check this.

Let $f$ be a linear map from an $n$-dimensional vector space $E$ into itself, and $\mathcal B$ a basis of $E$. Let $A$ the matrix of $f$ in that basis. And let another basis $\mathcal B'$, with a matrix $P$ of change of basis, which is regular. That is, if $v$ is a vector in $E$ with coordinates $X\in\Bbb R^n$ in the basis $\mathcal B$, then the coordinates $X'$ in the basis $\mathcal B'$ satisfy (note the order):

$$X=PX'$$

Now, in the new basis, $f$ has another matrix representation $A'$, that is given by

$$A'=P^{-1}AP$$

How does it impact eigenvectors and eigenvalues? Let $u$ an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $Au=\lambda u$ and, since $A=PA'P^{-1}$

$$PA'P^{-1}u=\lambda u$$

Hence

$$A'P^{-1}u=P^{-1}\lambda u=\lambda P^{-1}u$$

That is, $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$, for the eigenvector $u'=P^{-1}u$. Which we can write $u=Pu'$. For the eigenvector $u'$, we simply apply the change of basis: it's the same vector in $E$, only its representation in a basis changes.

That is, the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a linear map don't depend on the basis.

Note that for this we don't require $P$ to be unitary.

Comment: It is my understanding that the matrix associated with a linear map is with respect to two bases. I'm guessing from what you're saying, it's not possible to apply the change of basis to only one of these bases?

Comment: @JamesWright You are right. Here I consider an endomorphism, i.e. a linear map from $E$ to $E$. It's required to even consider eigenvalues. I changed the answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: Is it also correct to say that the matrix associated with a linear operator $f: E \rightarrow E$ must be with respect to one basis of $E$? Ie. the pair of bases maybe $(\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B})$ (in the case of $A$) or $(\mathcal{B}', \mathcal{B}')$ (in the case of $A'$), but not $(\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}')$?

Comment: @JamesWright Eigenvalues and eigenvectors are defined for $f$, and don't rely on a basis (here I proved that they are independent of the basis chosen). It's not impossible to use two different bases, but then the relation $Au=\lambda u$ won't hold, and everything will be more complicated. The relation $f(v)=\lambda v$ will have to be written $Au_{\mathcal B}=\lambda u_{\mathcal B'}$, then use $P$ if you want to at least have the same representation of $v$. I see no reason to do that, and I think it's not a very good idea.

Comment: Aha! Despite it not being a good idea, I think that example did clear things up a good bit for me. Thanks!